# List index out of range error while it’s not

Tags: range

I am just a beginner

```
f=open(‘m.txt’)
for lines in f:   
    if lines.startswith(‘From’):
        g=lines.split()
        g2=g[5]
        print(g2)
```

The line in the file is like:
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008(a single line)

It is showing index out of range error on 2nd last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you split using 'From', your code becomes something like this :

```
g = ['stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008']
```

Since size/length of g is only 1, it will certainly give u an IndexOutOfBounds error if you try to access g[5]

If you want to access the element at 5th index in the above phrase ('e' here), you could do the following:

```
print(g[0][5])
```